# Does Ember.RSVP.all.then take 1 or 2 parameters?

Tags: ember.js, rsvp-promise

I'm creating a function that sends off a bunch of promises and I want to let the user know what happened when they have all resolved. But, I'm not sure what parameters `Ember.RSVP.all.then()` should take. Right now I have something like this:

```
Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(
  (success) ->
    do stuff...
  (error) ->
    handle errors
)
```

But, I've also seen a pattern like this:

```
Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(
  (values) ->
    do stuff...
).catch(
  (values) ->
    handle errors
)
```

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an unfortunate flame war with an SO [Soup Nazi](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php) and reading through the source of this undocumented method, I've finally figured out what is going on.

`RSVP.all()` returns a promise so chaining `then` onto it takes 2 functions as parameters(referred to as `resolve()` and `reject()`). The confusing part of this method is that `resolve()` is passed an array of resolved promises where `reject()` is passed the first promise that is rejected.